# I am having problems using a IsValid method when creating a GUI

Tags: java

In my java class, My teacher gave us a GUI program that asks to tally up grades and gets a running average. But my problem is that we have to check if the input is not a double or a String of characters. My book has a method of boolean isValid () to check if it is an int,and says nothing else.I am using a server and a class This is what i have so far...(my tab will not work sorry).

Server:

```
`public boolean isValid(int number){
    boolean valid=false;
    if (number<=100&&number>=0){
        valid=true;
    }
    return valid;
}
`
```

Client:

```
`public void buttonClicked(JButton buttonObj){
//other code
    Tallyserver tally=new Tallyserver();
    tally.isValid(number);
`
```

I am wondering if i am using this method wrong or there is another way you would program this?

Comment: Welcome to SO, next time please post error messages if any, and what happens when you try to execute your code.

Answer (score 1):

Concentrate on one problem at a time.

The isValid method you have only validates if a number is within a range, not if the number is a valid int (instead of a String or a double).

Check out java.lang.Integer.parseInt:

```
/**
 * Parses the string argument as a signed decimal integer. The
 * characters in the string must all be decimal digits, except
 * that the first character may be an ASCII minus sign {@code '-'}
 * (<code>'&#92;u002D'</code>) to indicate a negative value or an
 * ASCII plus sign {@code '+'} (<code>'&#92;u002B'</code>) to
 * indicate a positive value. The resulting integer value is
 * returned, exactly as if the argument and the radix 10 were
 * given as arguments to the {@link #parseInt(java.lang.String,
 * int)} method.
 *
 * @param s    a {@code String} containing the {@code int}
 *             representation to be parsed
 * @return     the integer value represented by the argument in decimal.
 * @exception  NumberFormatException  if the string does not contain a
 *               parsable integer.
 */
public static int parseInt(String s) throws NumberFormatException {
    return parseInt(s,10);
}
```